# NVIDIA Controller on RetroPie?

Tags: retropie

I have been playing around with RetroPie and would like to be able to use my NVIDIA controller with it for emulators, since I already own one for my PC and I have gotten comfortable with the controls.

When I plug it into the Pi via USB and boot up RetroPie, only the "Back" and "Home" buttons on the controller are recognized. Is there a way to let RetroPie recognize all of the controls on this controller? I would like to not have to buy another controller just for using RetroPie.

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with RetroPie v4.2.

**EDIT (2017-05-29):** I have executed the `lsusb` command with the controller plugged in and (I think) the output shows the controller next to `Bus 001 Device 004:`:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0955:7210 NVidia Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**EDIT 2 (2017-05-29):** I have used the `jstest /dev/input/js0` command with the controller plugged in and I have mapped the controller buttons to the following IDs:
[image: RetroPie NVIDIA Controller Inputs]

**EDIT 3 (2017-05-29):** I used `evtest /dev/input/event0` with the controller plugged in and received this output:

```
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0x955 product 0x7210 version 0x111
Input device name: "NVIDIA Corporation NVIDIA Controller v01.03"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 113 (KEY_MUTE)
    Event code 114 (KEY_VOLUMEDOWN)
    Event code 115 (KEY_VOLUMEUP)
    Event code 116 (KEY_POWER)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 172 (KEY_HOMEPAGE)
    Event code 272 (BTN_LEFT)
    Event code 273 (BTN_RIGHT)
    Event code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE)
    Event code 276 (BTN_EXTRA)
    Event code 304 (BTN_SOUTH)
    Event code 305 (BTN_EAST)
    Event code 307 (BTN_NORTH)
    Event code 308 (BTN_WEST)
    Event code 310 (BTN_TL)
    Event code 311 (BTN_TR)
    Event code 312 (BTN_TL2)
    Event code 315 (BTN_START)
    Event code 317 (BTN_THUMBL)
    Event code 318 (BTN_THUMBR)
  Event type 2 (EV_REL)
    Event code 0 (REL_X)
    Event code 1 (REL_Y)
  Event type 3 (EV_ABS)
    Event code 0 (ABS_X)
      Value  32767
      Min        0
      Max    65535
      Fuzz     255
      Flat    4095
    Event code 1 (ABS_Y)
      Value  32767
      Min        0
      Max    65535
      Fuzz     255
      Flat    4095
    Event code 2 (ABS_Z)
      Value  32767
      Min        0
      Max    65535
      Fuzz     255
      Flat    4095
    Event code 5 (ABS_RZ)
      Value  32767
      Min        0
      Max    65535
      Fuzz     255
      Flat    4095
      Resolution      57
    Event code 9 (ABS_GAS)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    65535
      Fuzz     255
      Flat    4095
    Event code 10 (ABS_BRAKE)
      Value      0
      Min        0
      Max    65535
      Fuzz     255
      Flat    4095
    Event code 16 (ABS_HAT0X)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
    Event code 17 (ABS_HAT0Y)
      Value      0
      Min       -1
      Max        1
  Event type 4 (EV_MSC)
    Event code 4 (MSC_SCAN)
Key repeat handling:
  Repeat type 20 (EV_REP)
    Repeat code 0 (REP_DELAY)
      Value    250
    Repeat code 1 (REP_PERIOD)
      Value     33
Properties:
Testing ... (interrupt to exit)
```